# Where's the "flash tray icon on new message" feature in pidgin?

Tags: 12.04, pidgin

I've had this feature before, but in 12.04 I can't seem to find it. I've tried installing the pidgin-plugin-pack, but no luck.

If anyone knows about a plugin with this feature, please do tell!

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it!

Right click on the tray icon, check the "Blink on new message" box.